# I want to create a table from a restricted user account and give access to that account

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is this even possible?
This user account will have access to a few SPs & Fns in the database & 1 of the SPs create a new table. When creating the table, I want GRANT SELECT to this particular user for the table.
Can this be done?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to allow users create tables. But you might be able to do this by creating table inside of the stored procedure and allowing users to execute that one stored proc. This way you will not have to give them access to create table database wide. And have some control over what they creating.

Comment: Look into http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx (SYSTEM_USER) and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176050.aspx (CURRENT_USER).

Comment: @iouri But that is exactly what the question states.  "1 of the SPs create a new table."

Comment: My bad :/ Keeping comment to remind others to read the question :)

Answer (score 0):

If your stored procedure creates the table, why not just add the grant select statement into that procedure?